# Change background with javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a button that changes the background of my div.
I want to give 2 parameters to javascript function.

The ID of the div wich I will change the background
The NUMBER of background types.

for example...

```
    <div id="background" class="background1">
     <p>Choose a Background</p>
     <a href="javascript:change(background,10)" class="btn"></a>
    </div>
```

The function I want changes the class of the background DIV to
background1, background2, background3, background4... until 10 (the paramter)

I want a function with parameters because I will use in a lot of divs!
Can´t do it =(

Comment: are you willing to use jquery? This seems like an easy enough task either way. is change() a real function you wrote or just a placeholder example because you don't know what to put in that function?

Comment: Just a placeholder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
var nextId = 1;
var highestId = 10; //highest image Id

function change(DivId) {

    //Change the background image only...
    document.getElementById(DivId).style.backgroundImage = '../' + nextId + '.jpg';

    /*Or to set class instead, swap the above line for the one below...*/
    //document.getElementById(DivId).className = 'BackgroundClass' + nextId;

    if(nextId > highestId) {nextId = 1;}
    return false;
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
<div id="Something"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="return change('Something')">Change Background</a>
```

[Working jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gApWv/1/) (Given that I don't have your background images, I'm alerting what it is set to)

Comment: It was not me that made it...
Should I call this like 
<a href="javascript:change(10,background);"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a> ?

I think I didn´t was specific what the button should do, each time I click on it ... must sum +1 on the background

Comment: Ah, ok, let me update my answer. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I'm fairly sure what the OP is looking for here is to change the class, although I may be wrong. Based on how the question is worded I am guessing background1, background2..background10 are already css-defined classes with background images set.

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly You may well be right but I admit I'm unclear too

Comment: It's very clear in the question. *"The function I want changes the class..."*

Comment: @amnotiam Fixed (I missed that)

Comment: Thanks... I did it... but I get this error
ReferenceError: DivID is not defined
Calling <a href="#" onclick="change('cBack')"></a>

Comment: Check online please if you can http://www.diegomenezes.com/monsters

Comment: @DiegoMenezes looking now.

Comment: I've got a working jsFiddle here (Allowing for the fact I don't have your images)... http://jsfiddle.net/gApWv/ Just trying to track down your problem, 2 mins

Comment: @DiegoMenezes Your problem is that in the function definition you've got ... `change(DivId)` and in the lines below you're referencing `DivID` (note the capitalisation of the D in Id)

Comment: Heh, you downvote me because you posted an incorrect answer... nice. Guessing you also downvoted my question.

Comment: First, you're lying. I can tell that you at least downvoted my correct answer. Second, I first downvoted your answer when it was an incorrect jQuery-only answer. You then added an incorrect no-jQuery answer. As it stands, it's still not a very good solution. As the question states, this is to be used for multiple divs, so using a variable in that way would be cumbersome. Also, OP wanted to pass a number to denote the limit. This could easily be a different number for each use of the function. Moral high ground... right... no, just observing an apparent desperate need for SO magic points.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to new HTML5 features, I will use an attribute 'data' to store the bg count on each div, and I will simplify the answer by using only 3 possible backgrounds, but you can add as many as you want inside the array:

```
var bgs = new Array('images/bg_a.jpg','images/bg_b.jpg','images/bg_c.jpg');

function change(div_id){
   elm_div = document.getElementById(div_id);
   if((elm_div.getAttribute('data-bg') == null || elm_div.getAttribute('data-bg') == (bgs.length-1)){
     new_bg_pos = 0
   }else{
     new_bg_pos = elm_div.getAttribute('data-bg');
     new_bg_pos++
   } 
   elm_div.setAttribute('data-bg',new_bg_pos);
   elm_div.style.background = "url("+bgs[new_bg_pos]+")";
}
```

div_id is the id of the division you want to change, the function it will rotate through all the backgrounds of your array separately for each division saving the position on the attribute 'data-bg' (Might not be compatible with older browsers).

Also in HTML, instead of a link use something else, like a span, anchors will try to send you to some location:

```
<span onclick="change('my_div')" >Change BG of "my_div" the next bg </span>
```

Comment: +1 That's an elegant solution but note that the OP wanted the bg to rotate on each click

Comment: @Basic, I am sorry, I didn't realize that he wanted to rotate, it is not expressed on his question, please see my new answer, I allow each division to rotate backgrounds separately, no parameter for background index is required, careful it uses new HTML5 features.

Comment: It was mentioned in the comments to my answer, so no reason you'd notice that. Still an elegant solution. However, I'd suggest that you edit your existing answer rather than posting a new one

Comment: All right @Basic, question modified, thanks for the advice. Diego Menezes I hope this helps, simply copy paste de function and call it onclick to any element (dont use anchors).